# Getting a Border/background Around Slider CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

please see: [image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyDxE.png)

What I am building: [slider images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onvph.png)

I am getting an unwanted light blue border around my slider, I have tried to style out the :active psuedo class to prevent this with no luck. Below is my code (HTML equivalent commented out)

PS: I have a built in funciton rem that converts pixels to rems basically.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<div class="slider--toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
  <label for="switch">
  </label>
</div>
```

```
.slider--toggle {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  input[type='checkbox'] {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  label {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: rem(54);
    height: rem(28);
    background: $border-grey;
    display: block;
    border-radius: rem(200);
  }

  label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: rem(2);
    left: rem(2);
    width: rem(24);
    height: rem(24);
    background: $bg-light;
    border-radius: rem(200);
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  input:checked + label {
    background: $primary;
  }

  input:checked + label:after {
    left: calc(100% - 2px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  label:active:after {
    width: rem(35);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your CSS SASS? I can't seem to convert it to CSS

Comment: Yes it is, the rem(24) is the rem equivalent of 24px if that makes sense.

Comment: Great. Any chance of dropping the translated css on your original post? I fired it through a sass translator but it didn't work out.

Comment: Yeah here I made a codepen, of course the bug isn't happening there... so it might be something in my other files. Appreciate your time but I think this ones just a bug for now. https://codepen.io/tzzr101/pen/rNvxWwM

Comment: What do you see when you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility? It should be possible to find out exactly who/where is setting that pale blue. The code you have given in your question isn't complete enough for us to be able to help you with this.